# Mobile Test Workbench - iPhone 6

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I'm using worklight 6.2 and Mobile Test Workbench 8.6.

When I try to add a device like a iphone6 into mobile test workbench, I open the URL onto safari (protocol://host_name:port/mobile) and it loads fine.

However when I try to click onto the website on the button "Passive Mode" or browsing the apps the site just becomes unresponsive, like it doesn't recognize my tapping.

This is a new iphone6, fresh out of the box without any third party software.

Does this happened to anyone else?

In a previous test of the mobile test workbench, I've noticed that in a ipad air I couldn't install apps, while on the iphone 4s I had no problem installing it what so ever.
This leads me to believe there is a device list the mobile test workbench supports. Is my reasoning correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think that your iPhone 6 (I hope it's not already blended :-)) comes with an iOS8 release.
Mobile Test Workbench 8.6 was out of the box before this release.

My advice would be to updgrade to the 8.6.0.1 or the future 8.6.0.2 (soon).

Best regards, Alexandre.

Comment: :) Still intact and straight as a arrow.
Yes, I'm still using MTWW 8.6.0 and it seems that according to eclipse marketplace I'm up to date and the version 8.6.0.1 is not there to download yet. Thanks for the answer.